# Implementing Fisher Yates Algorithm

Tags: java

there I have method in java which randomize a number of integers in a array. But it take too long, I am trying to find faster method to do this , I think the fisher Yates Algorithm is the solution but i am not sure how to implement this with my code.

```
protected void randomise() {
    int[] copy = new int[getArray().length];
    // used to indicate if elements have been used
    boolean[] used = new boolean[getArray().length];
    Arrays.fill(used,false);
    for (int index = 0; index < getArray().length; index++) {
        int randomIndex;
        do {
            randomIndex = getRandomIndex();
        } while (used[randomIndex]);
        copy[index] = getArray()[randomIndex];
        used[randomIndex] = true;
    }
    for (int index = 0; index < getArray().length; index++) {
        getArray()[index] = copy[index];
    }
}
/*
 * A method which prints out the list of nubers
 */

public static void main(String[] args) {
    RandomListing count = new SimpleRandomListing(1000000);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(count.getArray()));
}
```

Comment: I've seen this before. Is it homework?

Comment: Did you end up using any of the answers? Because if you did, please mark the answer you used as correct.

Answer (score 0):

```
N = array.length;
for i in [0, 1, 2, ..., N - 1]:
  random_index = random(i, N - 1);
  swap(array[i], array[random_index]);
```

Comment: This not matches 'Java' as a language :-)

Comment: Yes, it is pseudo-something. My own personal brew. The question looks like homework, and for homework it is usually easier to understand pseudo code than code you would write as a 9-to-5 job.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an implementation of Fisher-Yates

```
public static <T> void fyShuffle(T[] elem, Random rng){
    int index = 0;
    T temp = null;

    //Fisher–Yates shuffle the 'elem' array
    for (int i = elem.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        index = rng.nextInt( i + 1 );
        temp = elem[index];
        elem[index] = elem[i];
        elem[i] = temp;
    }
}
```

You can also use `Collections.shuffle( collection )` to shuffle a collection (such as a `List<>`)